# How to create an URL in Blackberry program

Tags: blackberry

Can anyone tell me how to create an URL link in Blackberry, which opens a web page after it's been clicked?

Comment: What did you try? What are you having problems with?

Comment: i am new to blackberry and i am searching for the code for displaying the url link and it should open the web page after clicking on it..i have tried some code but it doesn't work...

Comment: Again: what code did you try, and how exactly did it fail?

Comment: do u want a label field ,clicking on which opens a web page

Answer (score 1):

```
// This can eb a nested class in your screen class. 
class URLButtonField extends ButtonField {  
    String url; 
    public URLButtonField(String label, String url) { 
        super(label); 
        this.url = url; 
    } 
    public String getURL() { 
        return url; 
    } 
    public void setURL(String url) { 
        this.url = url; 
    } 
}    



// member variable of your screen class- this will let you access it later 
// to change the URL
URLButtonField bf;

// In your screen's constructor: 

bf = new ButtonField("Example", "http://www.example.com"); 
bf.setFieldChangeListener( new FieldChangeListener() { 
    void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) { 
        if (field == this) { 
            BrowserSession session =- Browser.getDefaultSession();
            session.displayPage(getURL()); 
        }
    } 
} );         
add(bf);
```

You can then change the text or destination URL of "bf" at any time, and whatever you change it to will be the URL that is launched when it is clicked:

```
// In response to some activity: 
bf.setText("Example Two"); 
bf.setURL("http://www.example.com/two");
```